# How to Combine Two Independent Queries with an OR Condition in Solr 9.5

Tags: solr

I am working with Solr 9.5 and have two separate queries that operate successfully on their own. However, I need to combine these two queries using an OR condition, and I am unsure how to achieve this. The context is querying a nested document structure, and here are the queries I am working with:

```
sudo curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstart/select?fl=*,[child]' -d 'omitHeader=true' --data-urlencode 'q={!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}(+_nest_path_:\/productCategories +name_hh:*necessitatibus*)'
```

```
sudo curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/gettingstart/select?fl=*,[child]' -d 'omitHeader=true' --data-urlencode 'q=brandName_hh:*Preda*'
```

I wish to combine these two queries with an OR condition so that the result set includes records matching either of these queries. Could anyone guide me on how to modify these queries to achieve this?

**What I have tried:**

I attempted to concatenate the queries with an OR operator, but the syntax was incorrect, or the approach was fundamentally flawed.
I've also searched for combining queries in Solr documentation but didn't find a scenario that closely matches mine.
Any guidance or examples on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at the Boolean Query Parser documented in Solr Reference Guide: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/other-parsers.html#boolean-query-parser

You can use the bool query as your top-most query and add your two other queries as "should" clauses to the boolean. In the example below we put each sub query in a separate http request parameter and reference these with `$q2` and `$q3` in the bool query:

```
fl=*,[child]
q={!bool should=$q2 should=$q3}
q2={!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}(+_nest_path_:\/productCategories +name_hh:*necessitatibus*)
q3=brandName_hh:*Preda*
```

There are other ways to achieve the same, such as using JSON request API as documented here https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/json-query-dsl.html. This could be useful for very large and complex queries.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this query which work for me by using appropriate brackets and query parser with combining parent and child doc filter with OR operator.

`({!child of="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}) OR ({!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"})`

This basically forms query as bellow:

```
"rawquerystring":"({!child of=\"*:* -_nest_path_:*\"}) OR ({!parent which=\"*:* -_nest_path_:*\"})",

"querystring":"({!child of=\"*:* -_nest_path_:*\"}) OR ({!parent which=\"*:* -_nest_path_:*\"})",

"parsedquery":"BitSetProducerQuery(BitSetProducerQuery(QueryBitSetProducer(+*:* -(*:* -FieldExistsQuery [field=_nest_path_])))) BitSetProducerQuery(BitSetProducerQuery(QueryBitSetProducer(*:* -FieldExistsQuery [field=_nest_path_])))",

"parsedquery_toString":"BitSetProducerQuery(QueryBitSetProducer(+*:* -(*:* -FieldExistsQuery [field=_nest_path_]))) BitSetProducerQuery(QueryBitSetProducer(*:* -FieldExistsQuery [field=_nest_path_]))"
```

Hope this helps! Thanks.